# Using Mongodb to check existence of URL in small crawler

Tags: mongodb, lucene

I'm using MongoDB for indexing URLs in a small crawler. Maximum number of URLs in my crawler is about 500 million URLs. I want to search in the URLdb for checking existing URLs, but the speed of MongoDB in search is very low for this query:

```
db.hosts.find({URL:"http://myhost.com"})
```

My questions are:

1. What can I do to improve the search speed in MongoDB?
2. For my purpose, is Lucene better than MongoDB or not?

Comment: There currently isn't enough information to understand why your query might be slow. Helpful details would include: specific version of MongoDB, description of MongoDB deployment (standalone/replica/sharded) and server resources, and explain(true) output for the query. For open-ended discussion on improving performance you would be better starting a thread on the [mongodb-user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mongodb-user).

Comment: i use mongodb standalone and mongodb run on a good server(about 100GB Ram memory and a lot of Hard disk free space and good cpu frequency).

Answer (score 0):

1. [It's fairly well established in the documentation that the way to improve query performance is by adding an index to the field on which you are querying](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-optimization/).
2. The amount of information about what you are doing is insufficient for anyone to tell if Lucene will be better than MongoDB.

Also, if you are searching your `URL` for an existing URL so that you don't add a duplicate, then what you want is to [create a unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/).

Comment: thanks,i use mongodb standalone and mongodb run on a good server(about 100GB Ram memory and a lot of Hard disk free space and good cpu frequency). url isn't uniqu because url crawled again and again and insert into database

Comment: The original wording of the question led me to believe you wanted it unique. If you do not want it unique, just add the index without that. `db.hosts.ensureIndex({URL: 1})`

Comment: when i test db.hosts.ensureIndex({URL: 1}) for index urls, one error suddenly occured,this error means can't index by url because url content is unformatted and all characters occured in url.what can i do?

Comment: I would need exact wording of the error message to look up what it means because I don't recognize it from your description.